# confused about the intent of a function passed to a subroutine

Tags: fortran

In doing the following integral I don't understand shouldn't the intent of a,b be IN
 what is the intent of f? shouldn't all argument variables in a subroutine have an intent?
 This is confusing for me even though it works i Would like to know how?

Also, I see that x is intent (in) since y gets passed as the formal argument of f  in the subroutine.  I'm just not sure what is going on with the intents of the subroutine
also it seems like integral should be intent(OUT) right?

```
    PROGRAM MAIN
    IMPLICIT NONE
    real*10 :: integral
    a= 1; b =2;n=1000;
    call simpson(f,a,b,integral,n)

    REAL*10 FUNCTION f(x)         
       REAL*10, INTENT(IN) ::  x
       f = x**(2.*charge)*exp(-a*x**2 -(b/2)*x**4)         
    END FUNCTION f


    SUBROUTINE simpson(f,a,b,integral,n)        
    REAL*10           :: integral, a, b 
    REAL*10           :: f 
    REAL*10 h, y ,s                                  
    integer n, i
    ! if n is odd we add +1 to make it even
    if((n/2)*2.ne.n) n=n+1
    ! loop over n (number of intervals)
    s = 0.0
    h = (b-a)/dfloat(n)
    do i=2, n-2, 2
        y   = a+dfloat(i)*h
    s = s + 2.0*f(y) + 4.0*f(y+h)
    end do
    integral = (s + f(a) + f(b) + 4.0*f(a+h))*h/3.0 
    end subroutine simpson
        end program main
```

Comment: hows  it work without defining charge? and dont we need a CONTAINS statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If not defined, Fortran compilers recognize all variables as having `intent` of `inout`.

Procedure arguments, such as your `f`, are different and are not really `in`, `out`, or `inout`. If you do specify `f` as either of those, you will get an error message that says something along the lines of

```
  Error: PROCEDURE attribute conflicts with INTENT attribute in 'f' at (1)
```

Comment: Arguments with omitted `intent` and `intent (inout)` are very similar but not absolutely identical ... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880537/fortran-intentinout-versus-omitting-intent

Comment: @M.S.B.: I see, thanks for the link. One of these days I might actually read Adams' book :)