# Should the use of the INTENT keyword speed the code up?

Tags: fortran

This question is based on an answer to the post [Fortran intent(inout) versus omitting intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880537/fortran-intentinout-versus-omitting-intent), namely the one by user Vladimyr, @Vladimyr.

He says that "<...> Fortran copies that data into a contiguous section of memory, and passes the new address to the routine. Upon returning, the data is copied back into its original location. By specifying INTENT, the compiler can know to skip one of the copying operations."

I did not know this at all, I thought Fortran passes by reference exactly as C.
The first question is, **why would Fortran do so**, what is the rationale behind this choice?

As a second point, I put this behaviour to the test. If I understood correctly, use of `INTENT(IN)` would save the time spent in copying back the data to th original location, as the compiler is sure the data has not been changed.

I tried this little piece of code

```
function funco(inp) result(j)
  !!  integer, dimension(:), intent (in) :: inp
  integer, dimension(:):: inp
    integer, dimension(SIZE(inp)) :: j ! output
    j = 0.0       !! clear whole vector
    N = size(inp)
    DO i = 1, N
      j(i) = inp(i)
   END DO
end function

program main
    implicit none


interface
    function funco(inp) result(j)
  !!  integer, dimension(:), intent (in) :: inp
    integer, dimension(:) :: inp
    integer, dimension(SIZE(inp)) :: j ! output
    end function
   end interface 

 
    
    integer, dimension(3000) :: inp , j
 !!   integer, dimension(3000) :: funco
    integer :: cr, cm , c1, c2,  m
    real :: rate, t1, t2

! Initialize the system_clock
  CALL system_clock(count_rate=cr)
  CALL system_clock(count_max=cm)
CALL CPU_TIME(t1)
  rate = REAL(cr)
  WRITE(*,*) "system_clock rate ",rate



    inp = 2
DO m = 1,1000000
     j = funco(inp) + 1
END DO

    CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK(c2)

 CALL CPU_TIME(t2)
WRITE(*,*) "system_clock : ",(c2 - c1)/rate
  WRITE(*,*) "cpu_time     : ",(t2-t1)
end program
```

The function copies an array, and in the main body this is repeated many times.

According to the claim above, the time spent in copying back the array should somehow show up.

```
system_clock rate    1000.00000    
 system_clock :    2068.07910    
 cpu_time     :    9.70935345
```

but the results are pretty much the same independently from whether `INTENT` is use or not.

Could anybody share some light on these two points, why does Fortran performs an additional copy (which seems ineffective at first, efficiency-wise) instead of passing by reference, and does really `INTENT` save the time of a copying operation?

Comment: Important point: The Fortran standard specifies nothing about the mechanism by which arguments are passed, solely what the result of the argument passing is - the implementation is free to implement whatever method it wants so long as it gives the expected answer. Thus your question is unanswerable unless you tell us the implementation you are interested; be aware a different implementation may do things another way.

Comment: If the compiler cared about optimal performance, it wouldn't bother doing much at all in this program.  It could throw away everything between the writes and time measurements and still give you what you asked for.

Comment: @Ian Bush, thanks a lot, I see, so the statement in the answer I linked is to be taken with a pinch of salt. It still begs the question though, why would any implementation use such copying mechanism? It seems quite a waste of time

Comment: That was not my answer, I only made some edits to that answer. I adjusted your question accordingly.

Comment: @francescalus, I see what you mean of course. The fact is, even if I change the main program to   ```   inp = 2
    j = 0
DO m = 1,1000000
     j = funco(j) + 1
END DO ```  , which I guess forces the compiler to make the function call every iteration of the  ``` DO ``` loop, the timings are the same. So either the implementation I use passes by reference without this intermediate copying mechanism, or something else, would like to understand.

Comment: @Vladimir F Героям слава@, I see, please accept  my apologies I totally misunderstood. I would be greatly interested nevertheless to hear your views on this alleged copying mechanism when passing by reference, which sounds quite inefficient at first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer you are referring to speaks about passing some specific type of subsection, not of the whole array. In that case a temporary copy *might* be necessary, depending on the function. Your function uses and assumed shape array and a temporary array will not be necessary even if you try quite hard.

An example of what the author (it wasn't me) might have had in mind is

```
module functions
  implicit none
contains

  function fun(a, n) result(res)
    real :: res
    ! note the explicit shape !!!
    integer, intent(in) :: n
    real, intent(in) :: a(n, n)
    integer :: i, j
    
    do j = 1, n
      do i = 1, n
        res = res + a(i,j) *i + j
      end do
    end do
  end function
end module

program main
  use functions
  
  implicit none 
  
  real, allocatable :: array(:,:)
  real :: x, t1, t2
  integer :: fulln
  
  fulln = 400
  
  allocate(array(1:fulln,1:fulln))
  
  call random_number(array)
  
  call cpu_time(t1)
  
  x = fun(array(::2,::2),(fulln/2))
  
  call cpu_time(t2)
  
  print *,x
  
  print *, t2-t1
  
end program
```

This program is somewhat faster with `intent(in)` when compared to `intent(inout)` in Gfortran (not so much in Intel).  However, it is even much faster with an assumed shape array `a(:,:)`. Then no copy is performed.

I am also getting some strange uninitialized accesses in gfortran when running without runtime checks. I do not understand why.

Of course this is a contrived example and there are real cases in production programs where array copies are made and then `intent(in)` can make a difference.

Comment: I see, thanks very useful to me