# Fortran INTENT history

Tags: fortran, fortran90, fortran77

I am a little bit puzzled on the `INTENT` statement of Fortran. I will use a C++-like language to better understand your answers and better express myself.

As far as I understand, there are three possible statements:

- `INTENT(IN)` specifies a *constant*
- `INTENT(OUT)` specifies a *reference*
- `INTENT(INOUT)` specifies a *local copy* which will be copied back

What is the need for distinguishing the last two, `OUT` and `INOUT`? Is there some historical limitation that lead to this design?

To clarify: I am not interested in the differences as declared by the standard *per se*, I need a historical perspective on the introduction of `INTENT`: why and when, basically.

Thanks & Cheers!

Comment: As a comment: `intent(inout)` isn't the default.  Indeed, there is no default.  Having no specified `intent` attribute is different from all of those others.

Comment: There are a number of related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29737367, https://stackoverflow.com/q/2880537, https://stackoverflow.com/q/27304084, addressing aspects.

Comment: Yes, there are several questions relating to `intent`, however, I'd like to find an historical explanation. I am not interested in the technical modern side, but on when and why they where introduced.

Comment: @senseiwa That is probably off-topic. Maybe suitable for programmers, I don't know. They were introduced in Fortran 90 after the whole Fortran saga https://www.fortran.com/forsaga.html (long and unpleasant story). But read the other answers it will clear your misconceptions. `intent(inout)` is NOT the default and is not a copy out and in and you can read why in those questions and answers. Using C++ language for Fortran is a VERY bad idea, but ALL of them are like references, but some cons references and some references to a copy.

Comment: Especially http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29737367/difference-between-intentout-and-intentinout is the one to read and is probably a duplicate. @francescalus could add to his answer that `intent(out)` forces deallocation of any allocatable dummy arguments.

Comment: @VladimirF That's exactly what I'm looking for, and thanks for pointing out the differences with C++. Not easy to find "variable", "intent", or any other reference in the Fortran Saga, but it's a very nice read! Thanks!

Comment: I should have said "possibly" references to a copy. If there will be a copy or not is implementation specific and it is necessary only sometimes.

Comment: I closed it as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29737367/difference-between-intentout-and-intentinout , francescalus more or less explains how they are different and the need for their introduction follows from that. Comment under his answer for any specific clarifications.